# Xcode - Images not displaying on test

Tags: xcode, xcode9

When I test my Xcode project I don't get the image I placed in the Controller.
I've tried Cleaning the project, Cleaning DerivedData, and restarting a few times. What can I do?

[Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH0YT.png)

[On Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hW1p.png)

I have Xcode 9 beta 5 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue adding the Assets.xcassets folder in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section under "Build Phases" (You can find this by selecting your target project) hope it helps.